# How currval of sequence being preserved during the backup and restore in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.6, sequence

If I do backup and restore a huge db (tons of tables in it), will it run without any issues rather rising exception about duplicate key constraints of sequenced column(s).

While taking pg_dump (complete schema / db), how its taking the individual value of a sequence and altering the value with latest value of a table's sequenced column when we do restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the SQL script generated by `pg_dump` you will see that it generates a `setval()` call for each sequence exported. So if you have a sequence `test_seq` and the last value it generated was 42, you will see this line in the SQL script:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.test_seq', 42, true);
```

this makes the sequence return 43, the next time `nextval()` is called.

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) for details on the `setval()` function.